# The Series $-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{4}{6}-\frac{6}{7}+\frac{8}{8}-\frac{10}{9}-\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Stewart, in the answers in the appendix of *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (7th ed.), Section 11.5, exercise 3, claims that the series 
$$-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{4}{6}-\frac{6}{7}+\frac{8}{8}-\frac{10}{9}-\cdots$$
is convergent, but Wolfram and I disagree. I looked at
$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k (2k)}{4+k} $$
which is clearly not $0$.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You're right.${}$

Comment: the given series is not convergent since your limit doesn't exist

Comment: where and what Stewart claims that, please?

Comment: Answer to #3, Early Transcedentals 7E section 11.5.

Comment: Whatever the sign since the absolute value of the general term doesn't converge to $0$ then the series is divergent @Stefanos

Comment: My closed form may be wrong... I'll check when I get home.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. Signs are alternating.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Ok, thanks for the explanation

Comment: And exercise 3 in 11.5 of "Early Transcendentals" is $$\frac47-\frac48+\frac49-\frac4{10}+\frac4{11}-\ldots$$

Comment: @Timbuc : We must not have the same text.

Comment: Apparently so, @Clarinetist, though that is a rather gross mistake for that book...

Comment: @Clarinetist, I already have the 7-th edition with me. The exercise is correct, yet in the site of Stewart it is *not* claimed the series converges. In fact, and by means of hints, it is pretty directly shown that it diverges. Where do you say Stewart claims this is a converging series?

Comment: @Timbuc: Pretty sure it says "C" (convergent) in the answers in the appendix.

Comment: Oh, I think I know where: the answers at the end of the book, right? Yes, that is most probably a typo. It should be D, as heavily hinted in Stewart's site, and not C. Good. +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, since $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k (2k)}{4+k} $ does not exist.

If you know the following claim, this will helpful.

> If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.